# How to to click button following xpath element? - python, selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, xpath

I'm trying to click the following button:

```
    <tr class="">
<td>
May 09 2022 09:00
</td>
<td>
Ecole 1337, Parc Tétouan Shore, commune de Martil, CP93150 – Tétouan
</td>
<td>
No spaces left
</td>
<td>
<a class="btn btn-primary" id="js-piscine-17" href="/piscines/17/piscines_users">Add me to the waiting list</a>
</td>
</tr>
```

using the following code:

```
table = browser.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#subs-content > table')
time.sleep(5)
plc = table.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//*[contains(text(),'Martil')]")[-1]
print(plc.text)
plc.click()
```

This piece of code does print the text but it does not click the desired button.
some people might ask: well, why don't you just use css selector or id of button?
but I'm expecting the website to be updated, and there would be more buttons which i would like my code to click, but i have no clue what their ids or css selectors would be.
The only criteria is that it should have the word 'Martil' in it's "<tr>".

Edit: Thanks to @Dimitar, i was able to solve the problem using the following code:

```
table = browser.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#subs-content > table')

for row in table.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'tr')[::-1]:
    martil_row = row.find_element(By.XPATH, './/*[contains(text(), "Martil")]')
    if martil_row is not None:

        row.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'a').click()
        break
```

Comment: show me your imports

Comment: `import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in your code is that you are finding "td" element which is not clickable. The clickable element is "a".

```
martil_rows = []
table = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#subs-content > table')
for row in table.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'tr'):
    martil_row = row.find_element(By.XPATH, './/*[contains(text(), "Martil")]')
    if martil_row is not None:
        martil_rows.append(row.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'a'))

martil_rows[-1].click()
```

Comment: Thank you @Dimitar, this almost does it for me, but I want it to click the last button and not the first one (if more than one exist).

Comment: I've edited the code, but you have to test it as I am not near a PC.

Comment: I think this would raise and attribute error list object has no attribute .click(). not sure tho.

Comment: your solution worked for me with a slight modification. I've added the solution to the question, check it.